# Prisma + PostgreSQL -- Connect or create many-to-many relationship

Tags: javascript, postgresql, many-to-many, prisma

I'm trying to create a message threading system on my web app similar to iMessage. Every user has many threads they're a part of, every thread has many messages, and each message has many recipients. I've handled creating the message and adding each recipient.

But where I keep getting lost is creating the thread. I want to query my database to try and find a thread with all of the recipients (including sender) of the message. If no thread exists with all those individuals, then create a new one. The reason I'm running into an error is that prisma won't let me query by any field that's not unique. Is there a simple work-around to get around this?

Tried creating an array of 'users' and trying to findFirstOrThrow against my prisma database. Doesn't work since this list may not be unique

Comment: I want to do something similar to this:

`await prisma.thread.upsert({where: {participants: users}, update: { messages: { connect: { id: createdMessage?.id }}}, create: { participants: users, messages: { connect: { id: createdMessage?.id }}}})`